# Parse Java class (for code representation) to JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

In an android application I'm developing I need to get a json file containing some data to reconstruct the lines of code of a java class.
Is there any java/javascript library that allows to convert/parse a java class (that doesn't just have fields, but also methods defined inside it) in JSON format, and vice-versa?

**EDIT:** I'd also need to keep track of the whole project's structure (something like antlr?)

**EDIT2:** My bad, I wanted to store a java class code into a JSON object to represent it, I was also thinking to create my own json object, this way, by parsing the Java code and finding methods, classes, parameters.

```
{
    "file": "PATH/TO/.java",
    "language": "java",
    "from": 0,
    "to": 255,
    "classes": [
        "Test:2"
        //...
    ],
    "lines": [
        [
            "public class Test{"
            //...
        ]
    ]
}
```

But if a good starting point is present, that would be great.

Comment: The Java reflection API does not contain information about method bodies and their contained statements. The only thing you could do is looking for a tool that reads the source code of a Java class and transforms that into JSON.

Comment: If you need to transform Java code into JavaScript then take a look at this tutorial that uses GWT: http://www.mccarroll.net/snippets/j2js/

Comment: @NobuGames That's what I need! Are you aware of such tool? Or a good starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that existing tools (such as GWT) are "only" able to create functioning JS code that is meant to be executed in browsers. But it does not necessarily resemble the original Java class. Your use case sounds quite different. It looks like you want to represent Java source code as JSON data and you don't need/want to execute it.

I fear you may have to create your own tool for that, that meets your specific requirements. I also fear that this tool must be able to parse the Java code because using simple regexes for extracting the data won't help here much because of nested types (interfaces, classes, enums) and also because a single Java file may contain multiple type declarations (even though not encouraged, but it is possible).

Here are a few links for Java parsers:

http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/ (unfortunately only Java 1.5)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ast/ (discusses the Eclipse Java parser which is very robust and probably most suitable for your requirement)

You could also create your own parser using ANTLR as you suggest. The latest ANTLR version has some visitor pattern you need to implement in Java, as far as I know. You could implement a visitor that successively constructs your JSON output.

However, you really should use Eclipse's ASTParser for that, because you can easily iterate all methods of your class and get their implementation code as String.

Comment: Forgetting for a moment the JSON output requirement, do you know any library that can do it in XML or other output formats? There are some tools that do it with xml, like http://xmltranslator.appspot.com/sourcecodetoxml.html but unfortunately source is not available for this.

Comment: @Vektor88 I just found a related question here on SO that links to the following tool: http://www.sdml.info/projects/srcml/ I'm not sure if it does what you need but the description sounds promising.

Comment: That's a nice starting point, but I wanted it to be java, so that I could edit the project to make it output in a nice JSON format. I am reading with interest the ASTParser even if looks weird to me that nobody made some sort of plugin to convert a source file to XML or any other format.

Comment: I ended up using a java code prettifier and Eclipse JDT API to get a prettified code and the structure of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jackson library - http://jackson.codehaus.org/: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: I read about it, but in the documentation - after a short read - I couldn't find any example of serialization of a class including methods (not only getters/setters).

Comment: You can not serialize an object including the class to JSON, only the data is serialized.

Comment: Sorry, because I realize I wasn't clear, check the updates of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use GSON: "GOOGLE for JSON" it's a google open source JSON Library, it can convert Java Object t o JSON object and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

You have [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) package that convert Json String to Java object and vice versa.

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass {
private String mStr = "";

public String getStr() {
    return mStr;
}

public void setStr(String mStr) {
    this.mStr = mStr;
}
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonString  = "{ \"mStr\": \"foo\" }";

    Gson mGson = new Gson(); 
    MyClass res = mGson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class); 

    System.out.println(res.getStr());
}   
}
```

Output: `foo`

**[Edit 1]**

You can't store to `Json` class structure, only data

**[Edit 2]**

From your fix I understand followed thing:

This Json String represents behavior what to do with "text" file , suppose, you download from server. But no mater what inside Json String 1st of all you need to convert it to Object in Java (if you want to use Java) and after that according to rules (took from Json String) write any logic. For sure java code is able to generate Java files. Your example tells you:

- to get text from line ... to line,
- create file named xxxx.java
- copy it to ...

So use my example above, create class, lets say `Launcher`:

```
public class Launcher{
 private String file;
 private String language;
 private int from;
 private int to;
 private List<String> classes; 
 private List<SomeOtherClass> lines;
 .... 
}
```

Comment: I read about Google's Gson, but in the documentation - after a short read - I couldn't find any example of serialization of a class including methods (not only getters/setters).

Comment: With Gson, you can only load class with parameters. Json object doesn't contain methods, only variables and arrays/maps

Comment: Sorry, because I realize I wasn't clear, check the updates of my question.

Comment: Launcher is fine, but I'd also need some kind of parsing operation through the lines, to also store methods,variables,fields,parameters,etc. In a way to link them between other files belonging to the same project. So other than outputting my json object, i also need a solution to build it, for example I'm considering to parse the java file and fill some arrays to create the "references" said before.

Comment: Gson helps you instead to parse full file but only specific lines.